# How to add image in JTable dynamically

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

```
BufferedImage img = null;
        ImageIcon icon = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/" + imageString));           
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        img = ImageScaler.getScaledImage(img, 35, 35);
        icon = new ImageIcon(img);
table.setValueAt(icon, 1, 0);
```

this is my code. But image is not displayed. I need some help to find out where i went wrong.

Comment: The following link may help you ta add images to jtable.<br> - [Add iamges to JTable](http://www.coderanch.com/t/340043/GUI/java/Adding-images-JTable)

Comment: Use this link it will help. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941372/how-to-insert-image-into-jtable-cell - http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=125 look at this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- you have to read [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- you can put Icon or ImageIcon to the [JTable's Cell directly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)
- for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue with JTable