# Dynamically load Image in jTable based on database value

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtable

I am trying to load image in a jTable based on database value.

```
String query = "SELECT ID, CATEGORY FROM TATTOO_LIB ORDER BY ID DESC";
try {
    conn = new data.connection().db();
    stmtt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = stmtt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {

        //I donot know how to write these lines here...

        File f = new File("C:/img/" + rs.getString(1) + ".jpg");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(f);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{icon, rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)});


    }
} catch(SQLException e ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error In Connection!!");
} finally {
    try {
        stmtt.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }

}
```

How can I load an Image in the first column based on the database value.
I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346219/how-to-add-image-in-jtable-dynamically?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527477/different-imageicon-in-different-cells-in-jtable?rq=1). But I am lost somewhere. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Override `getColumnClass()` of the table model so the `ImageIcon` can be rendered correctly. See more at [How to Use Tables - Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            switch(col) {
                case 0: return ImageIcon.class;
                default: return String.class;
            }
        }
    };
```

Also `ImageIcon` doesn't accept a `File` argument. You *can* use `ImageIO.read()` to obtain an `Image` to pass to the `ImageIcon` though

```
File f = new File("C:/img/"+rs.getString(1)+".jpg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(f);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
```

You *could* just pass the string file path to the `ImageIcon`, but `ImageIO` will throw an exception is the path is incorrect, which is helpful

You'll probably want to set the row height and column width accordingly, also

```
table.setRowHeight(height);
TableColumn column = table.getColumn("ColumnIdentifier");
column.setWidth(150);
```