# Dynamically add images to JTable cells

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I am dynamically adding data to a cell with the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < matchedSlots.size(); i++)
{  
  String title = matchedSlots.get(i).getTitle();
   String director = matchedSlots.get(i).getDirector();
   int rating = matchedSlots.get(i).getRating();
   int runTime = matchedSlots.get(i).getRunningTime();

    DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) searchResults.getModel();    
    tm.addRow(new Object[] {title,director,rating,runTime});
 }
```

what do I need to add to the above to be able to add an image in the first cell of each row

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.gif");
...
tm.addRow(new Object[] {image,title,director,rating,runTime});
```

You may need to change your table model to account for the new column if you haven't already.

This short article should help you with the image renderer: http://mdsaputra.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/swing-hack-show-image-in-jtable/

Comment: I tried this and all it does is display the pathname. Rather than harding coding the pathname i used    matchedSlot.get(i).getImagePath

Answer (score 1):

By default `JTable` can render Images. You just need to override getColumnClass() in the `TableModel` and return `Icon.class` for 1st column.

Look at [Renderers and Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more details.

Comment: Look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941372/how-to-insert-image-into-jtable-cell) provided by @camickr